# Kubectl exec gives error Error from server:upgrade request required

Tags: docker, exec, kubernetes

Kubectl version:1.2.4
etcd version 2.2.1
flannel version 0.0.5

I have a four node cluster and all nodes are up and running. kubectl run works fine but I am not able to enter my container.I have tried updating the curl version to 7.47 but it still does not work.

Comment: Do you have a SPDY aware client? You need that for using `exec`.

Comment: I am new to this and I need this up and running to perform tests. May I know how to enable an SPDY aware client?